# Runtime Error - The specified module could not be found 

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-7-x64

When I run my application compiled as x86 I get:

"the specified module could not be found"

It works fine compiled as x64.  The application can be downloaded from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C). I need to run this class library inside a 32-bit app.

Errors I see in [depency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/):

> Error: Modules with different CPU types were found. Warning: At least
>   one delay-load dependency module was not found. Warning: At least one
>   module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a
>   delay-load dependent module.

Further info in dependency walker...

`IESHIMS.DLL not found`

This code causes the problem:

```
        s_MouseHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(
            WH_MOUSE_LL,
            s_MouseDelegate,
            Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]),
            0);
```

Later down the road...

`int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();//error code comes back as 126`

Any idea how to run inside a 32 bit app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global mouse event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607133/global-mouse-event-handler)

Comment: @HansPassant - Dangit Hans you saved me a weekend worth of work!! You are a genius man. I would be happy to give you answer credit if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an x86 solution platform via the configuration manager, and change the Platform to x86 for both projects.  "Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#" works fine as x86.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w(v=vs.80).aspx