# Creating a Windows hook to detect menu clicks

Tags: c#, .net, windows, hook

I would like to attach to a separate application (Microsoft Excel, for example), and detect when a certain menu item is clicked (or a ribbon command in new versions, whatever).

I thought I could do it using the `RegisterWindowMessage` in `user32.dll`, but I have no clue which messages to intercept. Ideally, I would like to generalize this and detect something like:

```
"menu item XXX was clicked in the app YYY"
```

I found this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18638/Using-Window-Messages-to-Implement-Global-System-H) which shows how to register hooks for events like creation of controls, application start/stop etc., but I couldn't find an example of how to get button clicks or menu clicks.

Is this even possible? Am I on the right track, or I need to take a different approach?

Comment: `SetWindowsHookEx` allows you to capture mouse events globally. See the last answer on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607133/global-mouse-event-handler) . It has a complete code sample.

Comment: @gideon: Thanks, but I believe this will only give me low-level mouse events (like coordinates). I thought that by intercepting windows messages I could determine the actual control which was clicked.

Comment: You could look into the accessibility APIs. They might be able to do what you need.

Comment: @Dilbert I was going to post an update but I just wrote the whole thing in my answer below.

Comment: @Dilbert Ah! I'm sorry! It seems I misread your post and wrote code to check for Right Click :S Changing it for a left click shouldn't be difficult though, as for menu items, its a little hard to PinPoint since sometimes menus are custom implemented. You could maybe use [GetMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647640(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the menu but this probably isn't sureshot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright, so I couldn't resist the challenge here :) Wrote a little program that does what you want.

**How it works** : `SetWindowsHookEx` lets you place a global mouse hook. **Now**, you get the `X`, `Y` and then use [WindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the `hWnd` of your target window. From here you can do anything you like, in my case, I sent a `WM_GETTEXT` to get its title.

This is what the program looks like implemented. Once you click `Begin`, it looks globally for  Right Click events, and adds them to the listbox. **Note** : It NEEDS to be a window forms app, the hook will not work with a console app.

[image]

Usage (Just create a default WinForms project and change it to this):

```
 public partial class MainForm : Form
 {
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    RMouseListener _native;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//start
        _native = new RMouseListener();
        _native.RButtonClicked += 
             new EventHandler<SysMouseEventInfo>(_native_RButtonClicked);
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//stop
        _native.Close();
    }
    void _native_RButtonClicked(object sender, SysMouseEventInfo e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(e.WindowTitle);
    }

}
```

---

Implementation (It's a bit of code ;) )

```
public class SysMouseEventInfo : EventArgs
{
    public string WindowTitle { get; set; }
}
public class RMouseListener
{
    public RMouseListener()
    {
        this.CallBack += new HookProc(MouseEvents);
        //Module mod = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0];
        //IntPtr hMod = Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(mod);
        using (Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule module = process.MainModule)
        {
            IntPtr hModule = GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName);
            _hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, this.CallBack, hModule, 0);
            //if (_hook != IntPtr.Zero)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("Started");
            //}
        }
    }
    int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;
    int HC_ACTION = 0;
    HookProc CallBack = null;
    IntPtr _hook = IntPtr.Zero;

    public event EventHandler<SysMouseEventInfo> RButtonClicked;

    int MouseEvents(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Called");

        if (code < 0)
            return CallNextHookEx(_hook, code, wParam, lParam);

        if (code == this.HC_ACTION)
        {
            // Left button pressed somewhere
            if (wParam.ToInt32() == (uint)WM.WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                MSLLHOOKSTRUCT ms = new MSLLHOOKSTRUCT();
                ms = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
                IntPtr win = WindowFromPoint(ms.pt);
                string title = GetWindowTextRaw(win);
                if (RButtonClicked != null)
                {
                    RButtonClicked(this, new SysMouseEventInfo { WindowTitle = title });
                }
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hook, code, wParam, lParam);
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        if (_hook != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hook);
        }
    }
    public delegate int HookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowsHookEx", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(int xPoint, int yPoint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(POINT Point);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, [Out] StringBuilder lParam);

    public static string GetWindowTextRaw(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        // Allocate correct string length first
        //int length = (int)SendMessage(hwnd, (int)WM.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(65535);//THIS COULD BE BAD. Maybe you shoudl get the length
        SendMessage(hwnd, (int)WM.WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)sb.Capacity, sb);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
{
    public POINT pt;
    public int mouseData;
    public int flags;
    public int time;
    public UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}
enum WM : uint
{//all windows messages here
    WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
    WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D,
    WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public POINT(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}
```