# On Mouse Down & On Mouse Up?

Tags: c#

I want to call a function when the user presses the left mouse button down and then call another function when they let go. However I need it to work when the user is not in the application. So for example if the user is playing a game and presses the left mouse button it will call my function etc... I have tried a few pre-made classes with no luck and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Low level mouse hook?

Comment: I shall have a google search :) Have any helpful links handy?

Comment: Here's a good example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx

Comment: here is a solution in a similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607133/global-mouse-event-handler