# How to get coordinates of a Mouse when it's Clicked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, onclick, mouseevent

I'm beginner in c# and need some help. After loading Form I want to display on Form coordinates of a Mouse when it's Clicked. Click can be made outside of the Form. For example in Browser.  Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the most simple way is setting [`Capture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.capture(v=vs.110).aspx) property of a form to `true`, then handle click event and convert the position (that is position related to top left point of form) to screen position using [`PointToScreen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen(v=vs.110).aspx) method of form.

For example you can put a button on form and do:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Key Point to handle mouse events outside the form
    this.Capture = true;
}

private void MouseCaptureForm_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.Activate();    
    MessageBox.Show(this.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y)).ToString());

    //Cursor.Position works too as RexGrammer stated in his answer
    //MessageBox.Show(this.PointToScreen(Cursor.Position).ToString());

    //if you want form continue getting capture, Set this.Capture = true again here
    //this.Capture = true;
    //but all clicks are handled by form now 
    //and even for closing application you should
    //right click on task-bar icon and choose close.
}
```

But more correct (and slightly difficult) way is using global hooks.
If you really need to do it, you can take a look at this links:

- [Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)
- [Low-Level Mouse Hook in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx)
- [Application and Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks .Net Libary in C#](https://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Despite my answer not only there is a way but it's also a good and simple one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't handle the mouse click outside your `Form` at least easily.
inside the form using  `MouseEventArgs` it can simply be handled.

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     // e.Location.X & e.Location.Y
}
```

Learn more about this topic at [Mouse Events in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171542(v=vs.110).aspx).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[`Cursor.Position`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Control.MousePosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition(v=vs.110).aspx) both return the position of the mouse cursor in screen coordinates.

The following articles deal with capturing `Global` mouse click events:

[Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)
[Global Windows Hooks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19858/Global-Windows-Hooks)

Comment: That's right but what if he wanted to handle click events? (as he said)

Comment: @MohammadChamanpara P/Invoke https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646262.aspx (SetCapture). EDIT: I've added links to articles that deal with `Global` input events.

Answer (score 0):

You need a global mouse hook.

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607133/global-mouse-event-handler)