# Create Visual Studio Keyboard Shortcut that include Mouse Click

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

**Is it possible to create a short cut in Visual Studio that includes a left mouse click?**

Currently, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> short cuts to Go to Declaration.
I'd like to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> to Go to Implementation.

I know I can create a keyboard only shortcut, but I'd like to include the mouse.

[image]

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38925495/bind-mouse-side-buttons-to-visualstudio-actions

Comment: @sthotakura - that answer looks pretty intense.  Hooking into the global windows event stream for mouse events?  Was hoping for something a little simplier?

Comment: I cannot believe this is not possible without a third-party extension or unreasonably intensive work-around.

Comment: @JoshuaKemmerer - I think this got better in VS 2017, but I'm not sure.  I've just been using ReSharper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know this is not supported by default in Visual Studio.

You can have **Ctrl + Alt + Left Click** to go to implementation with ReSharper.

Using ReSharper you have an option for this in ReSharper options:
[image]

ReSharper is a paid extension that brings a lot of great features to Visual Studio. I'm not affiliated in any way with ReShaper. I'm just a fan of the extension.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!!!  Even had the option turned on in ReSharper, just didn't know the key combination.