# c# Get (Register?) mouse events outside own app

Tags: c#, mouseevent

I have a window-less tray app (.NET Framework 4.5.2) and want to handle any middle mouse clicks on other windows (outside my app). How can I get/register this event including the cursor location (for further purposes) to trigger an own method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54746218/global-mouse-hook-in-c-sharp-application

Comment: A bit late, but thanks @dr.null - this worked for me: https://github.com/justcoding121/windows-user-action-hook