# How to count mouse clicks anywhere on screen in c#?

Tags: c#, mouseevent, counter, mouse, mouseclick-event

I have simple app and I want to count mouse clicks anywhere on screen. I have code but it counts clicks only in area where is label.

```
        int count = 0;
        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            mclickcounter.Text = count.ToString();
            //mclickcounter is label
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607133/global-mouse-event-handler

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global mouse event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607133/global-mouse-event-handler)

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook and https://github.com/Indieteur/GlobalHooks