# C# WInform Listen and Log Cursor.current

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am having a little trouble with the cursor. I am using some in house library that changes the mouse cursor to wait and back to default, depending on background processes. However, under some situation the Cursor will be stucked at Cursors.WaitCursor state. I want to debug it by listening to Cursor.current and log it whenever it changes to wait cursor. However, Control.CursorChanged doesn't seems to be triggered. Is there any Event Handler I can listen to, or is there a better solution?

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607133/global-mouse-event-handler

Comment: I have decided to ignore the problem and just set UseWaitCursor = false and GridControl.Cursor = null;

Comment: @D.Kastier I will take a look thanks