# Setting cursor position in WPF only works sometimes

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a WPF application and want to set the cursor position to the corner of the screen.

I tried using the WinForms approach:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
```

and the user32.dll approach:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
```

The WinForms approach worked sometimes, but I don't understand why it worked and didn't work sometimes. I made sure the code is actually being called. The user32.dll approach didn't work for me at all.

Comment: ...did you ever check the return-value from `SetCursorPos`? (And you need to add `[return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]`)

Comment: Did you try SetCursorPos with values higher than 0 for X and Y?  Try with 100, 100.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is make your application enough big and move mouse inside of it.
http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2017/10/move-mouse-cursor-automatically-c.html

To move mouse outside your application you need global mouse hook.
[Global mouse event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607133/global-mouse-event-handler)