# Hook closing applications

Tags: c#, .net, windows

From my C# application, I'm trying to get notification from another (specific) application when it is closing (just when its process ends). From what I found, hook on this process is a possible solution, but I didn't managed to make it work. Can anyone help me on that or propose another solution.

Comment: Refer this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102814/how-to-hook-an-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Process` class to do this, specifically, its `Exited` event:

```
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").Single();
// or Process.GetProcessById() if you have the ID
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Exited += YourHandler;
```

Comment: Incredible! Thank you svick.

Answer (score 3):

Use WMI to monitor for a process closing event. There's some [example code here](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2006/02/11/438006.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I've done these kind of things simply by checking a process every 100 ticks. it may be expensive, but that depend on your need.
u can use `Process.GetProcessById()` for that

Answer (score 1):

There is a really simple way of doing this, provided if the process you're after is a user-process, or you're running as administrator:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
Console.WriteLine("waiting...");
foreach(var p in processes )
    p.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine("notepad has exited...");
```

The easiest way to use this is to spawn a new Task that will run this code and then leverage the callback to do your aditional work after the process has exited.