# Window hook understanding

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process, hook

Recently I had to study about hooks. I got the hooks working but while reviewing it I wondered when does it come into the picture. Does it come into picture when

1. System message queue passes to winProc of the process?
2. When a message is received by **GUI thread message** queue of application?

I tried to make both flows. it will be great if anyone can validate my understanding.
[image: Flow a/q to point 1.]
[image: Flow a/q to point 2.]

One additional question.

I was able to implement global hooks but I tried hard for process-specific hooks. I couldn't. I tried researching the internet, I got not a single project which implemented thread-specific hooks. I found [How to hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102814/how-to-hook-an-application) this answer which says it's not possible but I didn't find any explanation anywhere. Can somebody throw light on this?